# Why QVector<TYPE*>::contains expects pointer to non-const TYPE as its parameter?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, stl, constants

I'm using QVector to hold pointers to Objects, say FYPE*, in my program.

```
    class TYPE {
        // ....
    };
    const TYPE *ptrToCst;
    QVector<TYPE*> qtVct;
    // ...
    if (qtVct.contains(ptrToCst)) { // Error!!!
        // ....
    }
```

The compiler says QVector::contains expects TYPE* instead of const TYPE* as its parameter. A const_cast operation would solve this problem. But it doesn't make any sense to me, since the contains method should never change what the pointer points to. And the equivalent code using STL vector works as expected.

```
    std::vector<TYPE*>  stlVct;
    // ...
    if (std::find(stlVct.begin(), stlVct.end(), ptrToCst)) { // Ok
        // ...
    }
```

What's the reason for this difference? Did STL treat containers that hold pointers specially, so that std::find accept pointer to const object? I guess partial template specialization was involved?

Comment: *explicit template instantiation* is completely unrelated to this, did you mean *template specialization*?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas sorry for the misuse of terms. You are right, I did mean "partial template specialization".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a quite interesting question about const-correctness and some non-intuitive errors, but the compiler is right in rejecting the code.

**Why does is not work in Qt?**

The compiler rejects the code because it would break const-correctness of the code. I don't know the library, but I think I can safely assume that the signature of contains is `QVector<T>::contains( T const & value )`<sup>[1]</sup>, which in the case of `T == type*` means:

```
QVector<type *>::contains( type * const & value )
```

Now the problem is that you are trying to pass a variable of type `type const *`. The problem at this point is that the compiler does not know what `contains` does internally, only the promises it offers in it's interface. `contains` promises not to change the **pointer**, but says nothing about the *pointee*. There is nothing in the signature inhibiting the implementation of `contains` from modifying the value. Consider this similar example:

```
void f( int * const & p ) { // I promise not to change p
   *p = 5;                  // ... but I can modify *p
}
int main() {
   const int k = 10;
   int const * p = &k;
   f( p );                  // Same problem as above: if allowed, f can modify k!!!
}
```

**Why does it allow the similar call to `std::find` then?**

The difference with `std::find` is that `find` is a template where the different argument type have a very loose coupling. The standard library does not perform type checking on the interface, but rather on the implementation of the template. If the argument is not of the proper type, it will be picked up *while* instantiating the template.

What this means is that the implementation will be something similar to:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename T>
Iterator find( Iterator start, Iterator end, T const & value ) {
   while ( start != end && *start != value )
      ++start;
   return start;
}
```

The type of the iterators and the value are completely unrelated, there is no constraint there other than those imposed by the code inside the template. That means that the call will match the arguments as `Iterator == std::vector<type*>::iterator` and `T = type const *`, and the signature will match. Because internally value is only used to compare with `*start`, and the comparison of `type *` and `type const * const` is valid (it will convert the former to the later and then compare <sup>[2]</sup>) the code compiles perfectly.

If the template had the extra restriction that the type of the second argument was `Iterator::value_type const &` (this could be implemented with SFINAE) then `find` would fail to compile with the same error.

<sup>[1]</sup> Note the choice of ordering in the declaration: `type const *`, rather than `const type *`. They are exactly the same for the compiler (and the experienced eye), *but* by always adding the `const`  to the right it makes it trivial to identify *what* is being defined as *const*, and to identify that `const T &` with `T == type *` in the argument of `contains` is **not** `const type *&`.

<sup>[2]</sup> In the same way that you cannot bind a `type * const &` to a `type const *`, you cannot do the equivalent with pointers, `type * const *` cannot be converted from `type const *`, *but* if `const` is added to both the pointer and the pointee types, then the conversion is fine as it guarantees not to break const correctness. That conversion (which is safe) is performed in the comparison of `type * == type const * const`, where the left hand side gets two extra `const`: `type const * const`. If it is not clear why this does not break const-correctness, drop a comment and I will provide some code here.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit template instantiation is done for concrete types, and you can be certain standard library vendor had no idea you'd write `TYPE`. That aside, the difference is in signatures. `std::find` is a free function template, something like:

```
template <typename I, typename T>
find(I first, I last, T value)
```

So, when you call it, compiler generates `find(std::vector<TYPE*>::iterator, std::vector<TYPE*>::iterator, const TYPE*)`. Since all `find` does is comparisons, and you can compare `const T*` and `T*` with no problems, all is good and fluffy.

`QVector<TYPE*>::contains`, on the other hand, is a member function, in a class template. So it signature contains the type used to instantiate the template:

```
contains(TYPE*)
```

And therein lies the problem, because you try to call it with `const TYPE*` — and conversion of `const T*` to `T*` is illegal.

Also: `find` returns an iterator, not a boolean. Your condition should be `if (std::find(...) != that_vector.end())`.

To directly answer "Why QVector::contains expects pointer to non-const TYPE as its parameter": because you told it to, with the template argument.

Comment: While you're certainly right, I personally feel that this is a severe shortcoming of Qt. It is by no means const-correct and that drives me nuts when I try to write const-correct code around it. Eventually, I removed most of my `const` declarations because it simply wouldn't work.

Comment: The `find` template takes the value argument by reference: `T const &`, as is probably the case of `QVector<T>::contains( T const & )` (I don't know Qt, but I can just imagine...)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez - dribeas: Irrelevant details.

Comment: It is a common source of confusion: if the parameter is `const T&` with `T == type*` why does it not take a `const type *` as argument? After all they *are* (??) the same when spelled out! (No, they are not, the parameter is `type * const &` while the argument is `type const *`) Agreed that it is not the source of the problem though

Comment: @arne: You are wrong in stating *It is by no means const-correct*, the reason is actually that it is *const-correct*. The type for which const-correctness is being dealt is the pointer, not the pointee, and unless you want to go providing specializations of all containers for pointer types, and then for pointer to pointer types ... or alternatively open up the interface of the function to provide looser coupling of the argument to `contains` with respect to the elements stored in the container (`std::find` approach).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I concede your point for this case. There are however a few places in Qt where I wonder why certain functions do not accept `const` arguments, which led me to my premature statement.

Comment: +1 at any rate, as the answer *is* correct, as you mentioned the `const&` is unrelated, as the compiler would have yielded the same error in any case.